# how to calculate how many time a page has been refreshed by user using jquery

Tags: jquery, refresh, reload, page-refresh

i need to count how many times a user has refreshed a particular page using jquery. The page should have a static counter which will increment  every time page reloads and if user navigates to another page counter of previous page should be reset to zero i don't want use session but do this using only jquery .Please help.

thanks im advance...

Comment: Can't be done I'm afraid. If you want any data to persist across page loads, you'll need sessions.

Comment: i can do this using php i am new to jquery so i asked you guys to help me i have very well said i dont want to use session dosent that mean i have tried something

Comment: This isn't possible, as Will says. Btw, it's a good idea to _show_ what you've tried - people here nearly always insist on seeing prior research, so they know the OP has made a good effort first `:-)`.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, JS could possibly rewrite the anchor part of the address - every time it sees a page, it could change `http://server/page#1` to `http://server/page#2` etc. This could then be read inside the JS - but a use case might be useful, to determine if this would be appropriate.

Comment: yes @halfer i just asked this  so that i could know how could i use jquery to solve my problem i know using php sessions is easy and quick solution to this

Comment: Coolio. Don't take the downvotes personally - I tend to treat them as a learning experience, so that my next question is better formulated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some hacks that could maybe do this.  I'd first ask what user problem you're really trying to solve because the solution is kind of ugly.

In pseudo-code, this is what you'd do:

1. When your page loads, get a cookie for the reloadCnt and get a cookie with your lastActive timestamp.
2. If the timestamp was longer than X minutes ago, then start reloadCnt over at 1 (the page was not just active before this page load).
3. If reloadCnt > 1, write the new count back to the cookie with the current time as the timestamp.
4. Then, in your page, start a timer that runs every Y minutes (where Y is about one half of X).  In that timer, keep updating the cookie time of last reload, but not the count.  This time stamp tells your next reload whether you just had an active page or whether the browser went some period of time without the page loaded.

The general idea is that you keep a reloadCnt in the cookie and you increment each time.  That part is easy.

You also keep a timestamp in the cookie.  The timestamp essentially contains the time that the page was last running in this browser (because the page is continually updating the timestamp).  If the timestamp is old, then the user's browser was not just showing this page so this must be the first one in a while.  If the timestamp is new, then this is probably just another reload.

Comment: i think problem i was trying to solve is far more small then this complex solution i was just trying to show new quotes everytime the user page reloads

Comment: @sohaan - Then, you asked the wrong question.  To solve your issue, just generate a random quotation server side.  If you don't want to do that, then put a list of quotes in the page and show a random one using javascript.

Comment: how to do it with-out using Cookies and Session ??

Comment: @AmolNavsupe - you have to store the per user page count somewhere.  The options with a regular browser and no custom plugins are cookies, session storage and on your server.  Pick one of those.